# Are these two duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [How to properly duplicate image for "clone" form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/101699/16495) but it turns out there was a similar  question I failed to find [Managed file: the file used in the field may not be referenced](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4433/16495)

The two are similar. And I honestly don't know if they should count as duplicates or not. The answer to the older one does not make it all right for me, but it got me going.

Comment: Similar, yes.  Dup, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions are about the same error message shown in a custom form with a managed_file form element; for this, they could be considered duplicates.

Since you seem to have a different solution, it would be easy not to make them duplicates: In your question, report that the solution reported in the other question didn't help you, and answer your own question.

I think this is better than closing one as duplicate, considering that the other question was answered from the OP.

Comment: Sadly, I failed to implement any other solution. I found that without hacking core it is impossible to do anything except what the older question and it's answer says. Marked as duplicate, because even when they are not *exact* duplicates, any non-core-hacking answers must be the same. If anyone will think he has another answer to my question, we can always reopen.

Comment: I closed it as duplicate. If you have any update and you can write an answer, flag it, and I will reopen it (or another moderator will do that).